# join a gulp stream with a file and re-save to disk

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

I have the *stream content* `spriteData.css` and the file `'./css/_sprite.scss'` which I want to write the stream content into, but not erase the file, just add to it, and re-save.

So basically I want to add to a file, so I imagine it would be something like this:

```
gulp.src('./css/_sprite.scss')
    .pipe( /* join with spriteData.css */ )  // This is the part i'm missing
    .pipe(concat('_sprite.scss'))
    .pipe( gulp.dest('./css') );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use *[merge](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream#merge-stream1streamn)* of **[event-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream)** that will allow you to do something like this:

```
var es = requires('event-stream');

gulp.task('whatever', function () {

  var sprite = gulp.src('./css/_sprite.scss');

  return es.merge(sprite, spriteData)
    .pipe(concat('_sprite.scss'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

Comment: Glad to have helped ;)